# PyQt5 How to set application name and icon in activities bar? (Fedora 29)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have Googled extensively and found plenty of hints on how to change my window title (which I know how to do), but this one is eluding me.

- When I run Google Chrome, the name 'Google Chrome' appears in the activities bar.
- When I run Eclipse, the name 'Eclipse' appears in the activities bar.
- When I run my PyQt5 application, the name 'Unknown' appears in the activities bar.

How do I change 'Unknown' to 'Dougs Project'?

(Virtual beer tokens may be awarded for correct answers).

Oh - and Happy New Year out there.   "8-)

Comment: eyllanesc - are you running Fedora 29?

Comment: Hmmm ... Fedora strikes again, perhaps? Thanks heaps for your help. I'll let you get back to your New Year party <chuckle>.

Answer (score 6):

I have solved it and, as I expected, it was me not Fedora. I was following some instructions on the Interwebthinggy and they were WONG! Can you believe it! I have since corrected my code and all is working as it says on the box. Thanks all for following this thread.   "8-]

For completeness, the code at the end of my source file now reads:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setApplicationName("Doug's Application")
application = mywindow()
application.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Even more curiously, the issue was with the declaration QApplicapplication(\[\]) which the groundswell of opinion seems to agree is correct (comments?). As soon as I changed the declaration to QApplication(sys.argv) the correct title was shown in the title bar. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: QApplication receives parameters that serve to configure the GUI, for example you can indicate the style or the .qss if you are going to use Qt StyleSheet, and one of the parameters is also the aplicationName, when you place [] you are indicating that the aplicationName will be empty overwriting the aplicationName you entered with the function.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks again eylianesc, Virtual beer tokens sent in your direction.